# Release pipeline design idea

Tags: build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to build a release pipeline having two stages Stage1 and stage2. In each stages I need to deploy multiple customers. I am getting the customer information from the JSON file using PowerShell script. Below are some of the questions that I need to solve

1. The above JSON file needs to be created dynamically using input from the customer. How to get input from the customer?.
2. Also planning to create Variable groups to hold the constant data needed for each customer. DO I need to create a separate variable group for each customer?

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer could help you achieve what you want? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question:

It is possible to [allow variables to be provided by users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#allow-at-queue-time) when they launch the Release job. As an alternative, you might consider creating an app in PowerApps and use the [Azure DevOps connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/#create-a-new-release) that PowerApps provide to trigger the job. This will allow you to create a more user friendly front-end.

Regarding your second question:

You don't necessarily need to, however you'll likely find it much easier if you use separate variable groups per customer.